# can't add more than 2 views to a viewswitcher

Tags: android, view, textview, switch-statement

In Asyntask, I want to change textswitcher text and If I add new view, app crash.
Code sample:

```
                textSwitcher.setInAnimation(MainActivity.this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            textSwitcher.setOutAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
            TextView tv=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
            tv.setTypeface(custom_font);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00285E"));
            textSwitcher.addView(tv);
```

last line gives error after I decided to remove all views and I added `textSwitcher.removeAllViews();` , then it gives null pointer. What do you think for fix ?

Comment: Which error do you get? Can you produce it here?

Comment: can't add more than 2 views to a viewswitcher error

Comment: post the whole class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewSwitcher can only have two children, as it says on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) for that class. I personally have not seen anyone using ViewSwitcher, it is an old class and you can get the same effect or better on your own with ObjectAnimators now anyway.

You can create your own `ViewGroup` that let's you switch any view for any other. If it were me, I would just extend `FrameLayout` and simply add something like this:

```
public void switchView(View view) {
    // add the new view and reveal
    view.setAlpha(0);
    addView(view);
    view.animate().alpha(1f).start();

    if (getChildCount() > 0) {
        // simultaneously remove the previous view
        final View child = getChildAt(0);
        child.animate().alpha(0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                // remove the child when the animation ends
                removeView(child);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely arbitrary behaviour. You can overwrite `ViewAnimator` similar to `ViewSwitcher` class and replace the 0 / 1 handling by a variable subview count. Really easy!